# Chrome emulator not recognizing media queries

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, media-queries

I am working on a website to work on handhelds. I am using media queries. The browsers are recognizing the media query and are resizing the layout accordingly. But when i try to test the pagen on chrome emulator it is not recognizing the media queries and is showing the desktop version of the page. I have included the meta tag for viewport in my head tag

and my media query css is :-

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
/*-----CONTENT -----*/

#mobileContentWrapper {
    display: none;
}
#desktopContentWrapper {
    display: block;
}

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
/*-----CONTENT -----*/

#mobileContentWrapper {
    display: block;
}
#desktopContentWrapper {
    display: none;
}
```

}

Can anyone please guide me how can i resolve this issue. Really apprecaite any help.

Comment: I'd rather use the media query `@media only screen {` placed before the first media query block. Anyway can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Why "only screen" and not "screen" ?

Comment: I tried by putting screen instead of only screen but still no difference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Device Mode Emulation Media Queries Not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888751/chrome-device-mode-emulation-media-queries-not-working)