# bootstrap 3.3.7 xs breakpoint doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, breakpoints

Why when do I go below 480px the four column doesn't stack one above another? The other three breakpoints work well but when I go below 480px the colums remain as they are located at sm breakpoint.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Test File</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="background:red">
          column-1
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="background:yellow">
          column-2
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="background:orange">
          column-3
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="background:aqua">
          column-4
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Bootstrap 3.3's [**`.col-xs` classes**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options) apply to screen widths under `768px`:

[image: Grid options]

Note that you're missing a closing `</div>` before your `</body>`, which may be interfering with your display. You can prevent these syntax errors by validating your markup with the **[W3C Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/)**.

You also need to make sure that your JavaScript is inside either your `<head>` or `<body>` tags, and that you have included jQuery (which Bootstrap's JavaScript depends on). Neither of these will affect your stacking, however.

Here's a complete, working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Test File</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="background:red">
        column-1
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="background:yellow">
        column-2
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="background:orange">
        column-3
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="background:aqua">
        column-4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Note that websites need the **[`viewport` `<meta>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)**
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` in order to resize correctly when viewed in the **[F12 Developer Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772704(v=vs.85).aspx)**. You should add this tag to your own websites, but for websites where it is omitted (like StackOverflow), you'll need to resize the browser windows manually to test responsiveness.

See **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888751)** for more information on the emulation bug.

Comment: I copied the code with the mistake and tested yours. I noticed that when I use chromium responsive emulator, I can't see the stack, but if I resize the window, everything work well. Maybe a problem with emulation?

Comment: Are you testing the code directly through StackOverflow? The problem is that for whatever reason StackOverflow doesn't have a `viewport` `<meta>` tag, meaning that the pages aren't resized correctly through the emulator. In order for responsiveness to work correctly, you'll need a `viewport` `<meta>` tag of: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`. I'll update my answer to include that.

Comment: Thanks I forget to add to the test page the viewport meta tag.